# 'pusher-angular' not works in ionic application

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, pusher

I am developing pusher application by using ionic framework and pusher realtime technologies. 'pusher-angular' dependency injection in app.js is not work in ionic application when I run it in android application. Any suggestion how to solved it? I want to enable $pusher dependency injection in controller so that I can use Pusher realtime API in my application. Any suggestion?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="//js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.pusher/latest/pusher-angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" >
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        db = window.openDatabase("chatChannel.db", "1", "Demo SQLite Test", "2000");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_channel(id interger primary key, chat_room text, last_text text, username text, chat_channel text unique)")
      });
    })
```

Controller.js

```
    .controller('ChatRoomCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope',         '$ionicScrollDelegate',
    function($scope, $state, $rootScope,$ionicScrollDelegate){

      var client = new Pusher('ed05a79be9c11b452872', {
          cluster: 'ap1',
          encrypted: true
        });
      var my_channel = client.subscribe(subscribeChannel);
      my_channel.bind('chat_message', function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $scope.messages.push(data);
      });

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console ? Can you add the code to your post (by editing it) ? Especially about the index.html where you add the script for pusher, and the controller where you use it.

Comment: @e666 I had included my code by editing it.

Comment: I don't see where you inject `pusher-angular` in angularjs. And also, do you have any errors in console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue I see is with the `index.html`.

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.pusher/latest/pusher-angular.min.js"></script>
```

This lines wont work in Android application but will work in browser. It is because android files are loaded from `file://` so it will try to load `file://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js` for example.

You will need to precise the protocol like this :

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.pusher/latest/pusher-angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ya, that is the problem. Thanks you really help me.